# reversePortait vs. reversePortrait orientation

Tags: android, android-manifest

I wanted to set **android:screenOrientation** to "reversePortrait" in manifest as described here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

but according to eclipse this is not correct. So I used auto code completion and it inserted **reversePortait** - notice missing "r". I was able to build and run the application and it worked fine. Is this some kind of bug or is my SDK messed up?

I didn't find anything about this anywhere. Did anybody encounter this as well?

Thank you.

Edit: SDK version 11 (Android 3.0), device Acer Iconia Tab A500 with Android 3.1

Answer (score 0):

What is your device's os version?? GingerBread 2.3.3?? if so it should work else it wont work as documentation clearly mention it

Edit

```
android:screenOrientation=["unspecified"| "reversePortrait"]
```

Try this it may work.

Comment: udpated answer check wheher it helps u out

Comment: I'm not sure if we understood each other. The problem is not that I cannot achieve reverse portrait orientation. The weird thing is that I did it by using misspelled value **reversePortait** because correct value **reversePortrait** didn't work and was considered incorrect value by compiler.